# How to connect two dataframes with one line Code

Tags: pandas, dataframe, group-by, aggregate, kaggle

I'm Solving Titanic Kaggle Code and Doing Data analysis with pandas. The Data is in here (https://www.kaggle.com/competitions/titanic/data)

I have two Dataframe and I want to connect them With aggregate code.

```
train_df[['Parch', 'Survived']].groupby(['Parch'], as_index=False).count().rename(columns={'Survived':"Count"}).reset_index(drop=True)

train_df[['Parch', 'Survived']].groupby(['Parch'], as_index=False).mean().rename(columns={'Survived':"Surviving rate"}).reset_index(drop=True)
```

And my Conclusion to connect those codes with column direction is like that.
But I think below code is very dizzy.
And There is another way to simply connect these two dataframes with one line code.

```
tmp_df = train_df[['Parch','Survived']].groupby(['Parch'], as_index=False).agg({"Survived": ["count","mean"]}).reset_index(drop=True)

tmp_df.columns = tmp_df.columns.droplevel()
tmp_df.columns = ["Parch", "Count", "Surviving rate"]
```

How Can I Connect these two dataframes with column direction
with one-line simple Code?

Comment: Why don't you try to merge them?

Comment: I want to try it with aggregate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your statement can be written more succinctly using Named Aggregations:

```py
tmp_df = (
    train_df.groupby("Parch")
    .agg(**{"Count": ("Survived", "count"), "Surviving rate": ("Survived", "mean")})
    .reset_index()
)
```

Comment: why did you cover the dictionary with keyworkd arguments ** ?